# batch file output to variable

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, scripting

I am executing wget.exe from a batch file I need response which I am getting from -qO-, but the issue I am having is greping "Success" from the output, so I know the call to the website worked.

Currently, I have

```
   FOR /F "Tokens=2,*" %%A IN ('START /WAIT wget.exe -qO- "http://url"'
) DO (
    REM Set "Version=%%B"
    echo %%B
```

Thus far I have tried  this as well. It works from a command like, but doesnt work from the batch file. Through the batch file, I see all the output.

```
  FOR /F "Tokens=2,*" %%A IN ('START /WAIT wget.exe -qO- http://url ^| FINDSTR Success'
) DO (
    REM Set "Version=%%B"
    echo %%B
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry thats a typo, I do have the escape character in my script

Comment: Formally: in `'START /WAIT wget.exe -qO- "http://url" ^| FINDSTR Success'`, why omitted quoting in `"http://url"`? And I'd omit the `START /WAIT `

Comment: @LeRay To answer your question directly, `wget` supports [exit codes](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html).  Why not employ [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution) to determine success / fail, rather than `findstr`?  Also, you probably want to redirect stderr to stdout.  `wget arguments 2^>&1` I think.

Comment: Hi Rojo. So I have a URL, that URL performs some tasks by talking to servers, if the communication between the webserver and other servers is sucessfull, I get a successful message, however if for some reason the webserver fails to establish a communication, I send back an custom error message. Would conditional execution work in that scenerio?

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't.  Communication failures would result in an exit code of 4 or 8, which would trigger the `|| command` part.

Comment: But the failures arent really failure, its just a simple reply back with the body containing "didnt work" e.t.c.

Comment: I was able to make it work, Josef. I omitted the START /WAIT, I also took out the FINDSTR as it was causing issues.

Comment: I'd suggest 'START /WAIT "" wget.exe -qO- "http://url"' - the first quoted argument to `start` is used as a window-title...